# Google Reseller API returning "Resource already exists" on Insert Customer

Tags: google-provisioning-api, google-reseller-api

**Dear Google Engineers,**

I keep trying to insert a customer and receive the following response:

```
    [error] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [domain] => global
                            [reason] => duplicate
                            [message] => Resource already exists
                        )
                )
            [code] => 409
            [message] => Resource already exists
        )
```

I then go about attempting to retrieve the customer resource that supposedly exists via a `GET` request to `https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1/customers/{customerId}` which fails to find the resource:

```
    [error] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [domain] => global
                            [reason] => notFound
                            [message] => Not Found
                        )
                )
            [code] => 404
            [message] => Not Found
        )
```

Either I've uncovered a bug *or* the error response from `POST https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1/customers/` isn't nearly detailed enough for me to diagnose.

I've tried variations of the required fields with random values (addressLine1, alternateEmail, phoneNumber). I've also logged in to the Reseller CPanel and no matching customer exists for the domain.

If Google engineers care to try and diagnose internally, the customerId in question is `ruby-stagingpop.co`. You can email me to find out my Reseller account if necessary. Info in my profile.

Comment: Short backstory.. you added some newly required fields recently (`locality`, `region`, `postalCode`) which initially caused the error `resource.postalAddress - Required field must not be blank` until I went in and added them. Perhaps this triggered a bug.

Comment: Is issue related to this recently opened bug? http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3346